# I want to create a Anonymous Inner Class in my java code

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
package com.chapter9.innerclass;

public class AnonymousInnerClass {

    private int i = 10;

    private void f(){
        System.out.println("AnonymousInnerClass f()");
    }

    public void h(){
        new Object{
            void g(){
                i++;
                f();
            }
        }.g();
        System.out.println("i = "+i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnonymousInnerClass aic = new AnonymousInnerClass();
        aic.h();
    }

}
```

As you can see I declare a new anonymous Object class inside my h() function.
In main() I try to use h() to make g() function work.But when I complied the code it give the following message:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error on token "new", interface expected
    Syntax error on token ".", delete this token
    The method g() is undefined for the type AnonymousInnerClass

What should I do? Please tell me the exactly way to use AnonymousInnerClass.

Comment: Read this: [Anonymous Inner Classes in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)

Answer (score 5):

`new Object{`

should be:

`new Object(){`

Answer (score 3):

Although in your case you just have a typo, in general the compiler will not know that the method `g()` exists, i.e., if you tried to call `g()` elsewhere it will fail.

Usually an anonymous inner class implements an interface:

```
interface X {
  void doSomething();
}

// somewhere else:
X x = new X(){
  void doSomething(){
    // implementation
  }
}
// this call now works.
x.doSomething();
```

Note that in Java 8 implementing an interface that has just one method is even easier with Lambda expressions and functional interfaces as per [this article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1).

Answer (score 1):

Also please note that as soon as you assign Object to any reference variable of type Object you will loose possibility to access g() from outside